# Magento2 missing theme and view names in static URLs

Tags: magento

I've created a custom tab in user panel with following one of many tutorials online. "Technically" it seem to work but on custom page CSS and JS files are not loading due to problem with their URL scheme.

Here is an example URLs from different page.

`https://example.com/static/frontend/Codazon/unlimited_supermarket/tr_TR/css/styles-m.css`

`https://example.com/static/_cache/merged/1cf2235f8adc378c1b685431fc4c1ae3.js`

And this is problematic JS from different custom page.
(Same CSS not enqueued here)
`https://example.com/static/frontend/_view/tr_TR/requirejs/require.js`

All I can say for a reason Magento not using my theme in this custom page and all theme related static content is missing but I don't know why.
My guess is some sort of priority problem, my module renders page before theme initalizes.

Here are my codes for creating custom page.

`app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-tab-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">offers/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Fırsatlar</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

`app/code/Test/Module/Controller/Customer/Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Test\Module\Controller\Customer;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/layout/offers_customer_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Fırsatlar</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-tab" template="Test_Module::customer/account/offers_tab.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

`app/code/Test/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route frontName="offers" id="offers">
        <module name="Test_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Comment: What styles and scripts did you define? And where? Did you run the usual `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and other commands? 
I didn't test it, but your code seems to be good to go?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your theme wasn't installed properly.

Does your theme show up if you go to Content -> Themes ?

If not, check the theme configuration and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

It could also happen if you're running Hyva, and the page matches a fallback page, but no theme was configured. (Or again, if the configured theme wasn't installed properly.)